# Java iterate through a file, to append each line to make one big string

Tags: java

i want to able to get add each line to a string. 
like this format String = ""depends" line1 line2 line3 line4 line5 /depends""

so in essensce i want to itereate over each line and from "depends" to "/depends" including them from end to to end in a string. How do i go about to doing this?

```
 while(nextLine != "</depends>"){
    completeString = line + currentline;
}


<depends>
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
</depends
```

Comment: `while(!"</depends>".equals(nextLine)) {`

Comment: Sidenote: use a StringBuilder instead of normal String concatenation. It will be faster, and you won't waste memory with unused Strings.

Comment: If you are using xml you could use a dom parser. Ex. Dom4j

Comment: @stuXnet With the caveat that string concatenation uses a string builder behind the scenes.

Comment: yes i am trying to convert xml file to json which contains few blocks

Comment: @DaveNewton yes and no, iirc. Actually, `line + currentline` would become `new StringBuilder().append(line).append(currentline).toString()` or something like this, but Java won't use the same `StringBuilder` for all iterations, but create a new one everytime. So you should use `StringBuilder` if you're using loops.

Comment: @stuXnet Oh, right, forgot about that--good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path to your file"));
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
String nextLine = br.readLine();//skip first <depends>

while(nextLine != null && !nextLine.equals("</depends>"))//not the end of the file and not the closing tag
{
    sb.append(nextLine);
    nextLine = br.readLine();
}

final String completeString = sb.toString();
```

Comment: +1 for taking into consideration the `null` value of `nextLine`

Answer (score 1):

In java `!=` wouldn't work for String so you have to use `while(!nextLine.equals("</depends>")`. Also it is better to use `StringBuilder` and append new line to it than using `String`. `String` in java is [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) and because of that, `StringBuilder` is highly recommended in your case.

This is a general answer for any input file, but if your input file is `xml` there are many good java libraries for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you could use java 8

```
Files
    .lines(pathToFile)
    .filter(s -> !s.equals("<depends>") && !s.equals("</depends>"))
    .reduce("", (a, b) -> a + b));
```

quite nice version ;)